# YouTubePlayer pod crashes when loading video ID

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to do something very basic, I have an outlet that is assigned with the YouTubePlayerView class and once loading an ID, it crashes.
Why is it crashing?
I checked that the outlet is connected properly and the debugger shows that videoId is defined correctly.

code:

```
import UIKit
import YouTubePlayer
class InfoViewController: UIViewController {

var videoId = "Bgh9u7x8i4Y"
@IBOutlet var youtubePlayer: YouTubePlayerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.youtubePlayer.loadVideoID(videoId)
}

@IBAction func exit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMainFromInfo", sender: self)

}
```

}

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: clean and run once,

Comment: Does not work..

Comment: i m not assign the downvote

Comment: I think it was YTPLayerview, So I answered based on YTPLayerview, but you are used YouTubePlayerView

Comment: now happy......

Comment: Yes I am happy, thanks. I do not want my account blocked because that guy that deleted his answer gets back at me since his answer was totally not in context. Appreciated!

Comment: @EricAya I did not accuse him! I accuse someone else that answered and then deleted his answer. I am sorry if it seems like I accused him.

Comment: @EricAya so you are implying I should take a screenshot of bad answers so I can prove it later when they downvote my question?...

Comment: I'm telling you that questions should include *code*, not a screenshot of code.

Comment: @EricAya I will edit it.

Comment: @EricAya - in my small suggestion, SO is not a place to gain the marks , its the one of the good place to learn with good concepts, so in my knowledge mark is not a constarin, but at the same time I hate downvoters

Comment: @EricAya do you have an idea why I get this crash? Why is my question crap? is there any missing information that will help understand why it crashes? It seems like there is no tolerance. People are trying their best here. I took your advice and added code.

Comment: @EricAya I appreciate your apology. Seriously, sometimes it is scary to ask questions. Once you told me what is wrong with my question I edited it. Regarding asking for votes, it is just that I was frustrated that I get downvoted without an explanation why. It is really hard to make progress when there is no feedback. I believe that if someone downvotes he should comment what is wrong otherwise it is just hostility. Anyways, have a good day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am still not sure what causes the crash, I believe it is something related to the framework, and choosing the type of a UIView (and setting it as a YouTubePlayerView through the identity inspector) added in Storyboard caused a crash when trying to load the videoId.

The work around was to add the player programatically. I used a plain view in storyboard to make it easy to give my player a frame when initializing it. But otherwise programatically works smoothly.
code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var viewForPlayer: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let frameForPlayer = viewForPlayer.frame
        let player = YouTubePlayerView(frame: frameForPlayer)
        player.loadVideoID(InstructionsVideoId)
        player.play()
        self.view.addSubview(player)
    }
```